# Script throws internal server error after a while

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a cron script that basically updates my database from an API. It runs for about 5-10 mins and was working fine in till a few days ago. Now it throws an internal server error after about 4-5 mins. I'm running on Codeigniter under development settings so error displaying should be working, but on top I have added:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set("error_log", "/var/sites/l/SITE.com/php-error.log");
    error_log( "File Test" );
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

But it still just goes to internal server error without showing any errors and no errors appear in the log (The "File test" does appear though).

Comment: 4-5 minutes implies it's in the middle of running something, possibly an out of memory error? Try checking your PHP error log.

Comment: How does a cron job show a server error? There should be no server involved in a cron job...?!?!

Comment: I can't check the PHP error log, On shared hosting and cannot find it. Thats why I tried to set a new log. But on PHPinfo under memory I have 128MB.

Comment: @deceze doesn't cron job run on a server? They can as well call php scripts, which can send automated mail with error messages, which in turn *can* contain internal server errors

Comment: @deceze I'm testing it in browser as there would be no log of the cron job finishing (custom logging).

Comment: @Félix But there should be no *web server* involved in running a cron job. Hence it's just a PHP script running on *a machine*.

Comment: @Tristan I'd say that's your problem. The web server is probably killing the script. Long-running scripts shouldn't be run via a web server.

Comment: I have some cron jobs that take up to 6 hours to complete, before you say anything, that's querying 6-10 million rows of CSV data.  Does the script output anything?, what os are you on? did you use >> /dev/null 2>&1, I found our server CentOs 5 has an output limit from cron at about 2MB, then it hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this

```
register_shutdown_function(function(){
     $lasterror = error_get_last();
     $e = var_export($lasterror, true);
     print_r($e);
     file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/error.txt', $e);
});
```

That will dump the last error into a file.  Should give you output like this

```
array (
  'type' => 4,
  'message' => 'syntax error, unexpected \'}\'',
  'file' => 'C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\test_site\\Sky\\Core\\Jet\\Jet.php',
  'line' => 45,
)
```

I should mention this will work for out of Memory issues, too..

Comment: What was the problem just curious, that was my nuclear option ... lol ... shutdown handlers can be really powerful on cron or background jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs tend to bypass the web server and are executed directly with PHP, so it won't show anything in the error log. Unless you have redirected the output to null (in the cron command), the output of the cron job should be sent to your email address.